Does a websocket proxy setup make a "direct" connection to the proxyed server when connected?
I am setting up a nginx server and configuring it to proxy a websocket server that is on another internal port in another process.
When the http connects to the proxy initially with http/https does the connection provide an ephemeral port that goes direct to the websocked server for the connection or does it have to copy all the packets and forward them ?  how does it handle https in such a case ?

does it have to copy all the packets and forward them? Yes, AFAIK, like with any other proxied connection. Unless you implement some PING/PONG mechanism, connection will be reset according to proxy_read_timeout directive value (default is 60 seconds). how does it handle https in such a case? As any other proxied HTTP connection, doing SSL termination and reestablishing plain HTTP connection to the upstream.

See also What value to set for proxy_read_timeout in Nginx to prevent WebSocket timeout in browser Q/A.

You want to serve UDP over TCP, might work, but it's another baby, that needs his own route. The best to do is to create a subdomain such as wss.yourdomain.com and that's it, no HTTP on this route.
